# 2 digit years using strptime() is not able to parse birthdays very well

Tags: python, strptime, 2-digit-year

Consider the following birthdays (as `dob`):

- 1-Jun-68
- 1-Jun-69

When parsed with Python’s `datetime.strptime(dob, '%d-%b-%y')` will yield:

- `datetime.datetime(2068, 6, 1, 0, 0)`
- `datetime.datetime(1969, 6, 1, 0, 0)`

Well of course they’re supposed to be born in the same decade but now it’s not even in the same century!

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) this is perfectly valid behaviour:

> When 2-digit years are accepted, they are converted according to
>   the POSIX or X/Open standard: values 69-99 are mapped to 1969-1999,
>   and values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.

I understand why the function is set up like this but is there a way to work around this? Perhaps with defining your own ranges for 2-digit years?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're always using it for birthdays, just subtract 100 if the year is after now:

```
if d > datetime.now():
    d = datetime(d.year - 100, d.month, d.day)
```

Comment: It's nearly always a good idea to do this kind of sanity testing.

Comment: Good answer - depending on the actual usage situations for this, subtracting 100 years for dates in the future is probably a good way to handle birthdays.

Comment: This seems a sane answer for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting that this does not work for people born over 100 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

This function shifts the year to 1950:

```
def millenium(year, shift=1950):
    return (year-shift)%100 + shift
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting a birthday, you could always just manually massage the data - any date in the future is automatically set back a century, or some such.